# Is there a reasonably complete online database of science-fiction works?

Tags: online-resources

Is there a reasonably complete online database of sf works?

- For written sf: the [Internet Speculative Fiction Database](https://www.isfdb.org/)
- For movies: the [Internet Movie Database](http://imdb.com/)

What about other media, such as comics, and radio programs?

(SF as in speculative fiction: science fiction, alternate history, fantasy… Note that I'm looking for a database aiming at exhaustivity in its domain, not a selection based on notability or tastes.)

Comment: had a good search last, seems their aint one, which is shocking really. One needs to be started to seperate it away from Speculative Fiction, which is a superset and includes lots and lots fantasy of dubious quality.

Comment: Science fiction is large.  Use library catalogs and meta-catalogs.

Answer (score 9):

Pick your poison…

**General Reference**

- [AudioBooksForFree](http://www.audiobooksforfree.com/browse/Fiction/Science-Fiction) — Free sci-fi audiobooks including a handful of classics
- [epguides.com](http://epguides.com/menu/sf.shtml) — An index to episode guides for sci-fi/fantasy TV shows
- [Feminist Sci-Fi](http://feministsf.org/) — Linked bibliography of feminist sci-fi, fantasy and utopia resources
- [GEOS (SF Television)](http://www.geos.tv/) — Comprehensive opinion survey of current shows
- [Internet Movie Database](http://us.imdb.com/) Lots of info about films of all kind, including sci-fi
- [Internet Speculative Fiction DataBase](http://isfdb.org/) Massive database of genre literature
- [Locus online](http://www.locusmag.com/) Extensive database, news, reviews, award info & links
- [Quiet Earth](http://www.quietearth.us/) Dedicated to genre film and all things post apocalyptic
- [Saturn Awards](http://www.saturnawards.org/) Sci-fi awards organisation focussing on film and television
- [Sci-Fi Movie Page](http://www.scifimoviepage.com/) Movie & DVD Reviews, trailers & clips,  and news on upcoming movies
- [Science Fiction & Fantasy Writers of America](http://www.sfwa.org/) Pure sci-fi class with no dross
- [Science Fiction Awards Watch](http://www.sfawardswatch.com/) Monitors and discusses sci-fi awards
- [SF Booklist](http://www.sfbooklist.co.uk/) A good user-friendly sci-fi/fantasy bibliography
- [SciFan Books & Links](http://www.scifan.com/) Terrific resource for fans of sci-fi literature
- [Technovelgy.com](http://technovelgy.com) Where science meets fiction in classic SF literature
- [Ultimate SF Web Guide](http://www.magicdragon.com/UltimateSF/SF-Index.html) A vast collection of sci-fi resources
- [Variety SF](http://variety-sf.blogspot.com/) A blogspot specialising in sci-fi literature, with plenty of short fiction
- [Wikipedia SF Television](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_science_fiction_television) On-line encyclopedia with lots of info on sci-fi TV
  (See also [Wikipedia SF Films](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_science_fiction_films) and [Wikipedia SF Novels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_science_fiction_novels))

and of course

- [StackExchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) A collaboratively edited question and answer site

**Search Engines/Directories**

- [SciFi Source](http://www.scifisource.com/) Comprehensive directory of sci-fi sites
- [SF Crowsnest](http://www.sfcrowsnest.com) Europe's premier SFF website has a searchable directory
- [Speculative Vision](http://speculativevision.com/) Good directory covering all speculative fiction genres

**Other Lists**

- [ArtsForge Sci-Fi 100s](http://www.artsforge.com/film/scifi.html) Artistic community site with sci-fi books and films lists
- [Boston Globe TV 50](http://www.boston.com/ae/tv/gallery/topscifishows/) A one-at-a-time SFTV top 50, starting at the end
- [Carver Recommended](http://www.starrigger.net/recommended.htm) Author Jeffrey A Carver lists his SFF recommendations
- [Classics of Sci-Fi](http://classics.jameswallaceharris.com/Lists/ByRank.php) Survey of classic sci-fi books by James Wallace Harris
- [Darkweb Online](http://www.darkwebonline.com/top100.asp) An interesting list of the Top 100 Sci-Fi Films
- [Examiner](http://www.examiner.com/article/top-100-highest-rated-sci-fi-films-of-all-time-2010) Top 100 sci-fi films of all-time based on a web-ratings survey in 2010
- [Flickchart](http://www.flickchart.com/Charts.aspx?genre=Science+Fiction) All-time best sci-fi movie list from interactive website
- [Goodreads Best Science Fiction](http://www.goodreads.com/list/show/19341.Best_Science_Fiction) Well-maintained sci-fi book list aiming for genre purity
- [Gunn's Basic Library](http://www.ku.edu/%7esfcenter/sflib.htm) James Gunn helped bring academic credibility to sci-fi
- [IGN](http://au.ign.com/articles/2011/02/21/top-50-sci-fi-tv-shows) IGN's version of the top 50 sci-fi TV shows of all-time, with a slight surprise at #1
- [IMDb Sci-Fi Top 50](http://us.imdb.com/Charts/Votes/sci-fi) Top 50 and Bottom 10 SF movies with links to the database
- [Internet Book List](http://www.iblist.com/list_by_rating.php?type=book&key=&by=&next=0&minvotes=40&oldgenre=1&genre=77) A clever online database where visitors can rate titles by genre
- [ISFDB Top 100s](http://isfdb.org/top100.html) Book lists based on speculative fiction awards/nominations
- [Mania](http://www.mania.com/greatest-scifi-horror-fantasy-films-all-time_article_19667.html) Greatest sci-fi, fantasy and horror films of all time
- [NPR's Top 100](http://www.npr.org/2011/08/11/139085843/your-picks-top-100-science-fiction-fantasy-books) Top 100 sci-fi/fantasy books based on a 2011 poll by NPR
- [Pringle's Top 100](http://www.listology.com/content_show.cfm/content_id.3064) Somewhat dated list of David Pringle's Top 100 SF books
- [Rate-it-All Films](http://www.rateitall.com/topic.aspx?OrderBy=&gender=B&Age=0&TopicID=446&show=all) Allows visitors the chance to vote on their favourite genre films
- [RT's Journey Through Sci-Fi](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/features/special/2007/scifi/) The Rotten Tomatoes version of the top 100 genre films
- [Total Film](http://www.totalfilm.com/features/the-50-greatest-sci-fi-movies-ever/) Another version from 2011 of the 50 greatest sci-fi movies ever
- [TV.com](http://www.tv.com/shows/category/science-fiction/) List of the Top 100 sci-fi TV shows as voted by TV.com visitors
- [Public Domain Torrents](http://www.publicdomaintorrents.com/nshowcat.html?category=scifi) Download cheesy public domain sci-fi movies and serials for free
- [Solar Guard](http://www.solarguard.com/sghome.htm) Comprehensive 1950s sci-fi TV site and discussion page

If that doesn't fit your needs, I could always provide more… but this should help on your quest.

Answer (score 8):

I would also add [Fantastic Fiction](http://www.fantasticfiction.co.uk/) as another source for written SF.

Answer (score 5):

The [wikipedia portal on Sci-Fi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal%3aSpeculative_fiction/Science_fiction) is a good start. It's not the best, but it is a very good one.

I think it is a main starting point to develop a full SF database.

Comment: I wouldn't count Wikipedia as “reasonably complete”. IMDB and ISFDB have no notability requirement.

Comment: IMDB is movie centered. ISFDB is book centered. Wikipedia is an starting point agnostically centered.

Comment: @Gilles, me. There is a vast number of good sf books that will NEVER make into wikipedia. Deletionists are too strong.

Answer (score 1):

http://sf-encyclopedia.com/
I found Science Fiction Encyclopedia to be most fruitful! They even have artists in the mix of literary greats; the list goes on extensively.

Answer (score 0):

Although still currently incomplete, [Elders of Genova](http://eldersofgenova.com/) is working very hard at creating the world's first unabridged encyclopedia of science fiction and fantasy. It is unique in that it also catalogs the fantastic elements in each work and allows you to do cross-medium searches for similar forms of entertainment. E.g. you can click on Star Trek and see that they have laser weapons in that franchise, then you can see all of the other works that have laser weapons as well.

As a user generated encyclopedia, even though it is still in early stages, it is growing very fast.

Comment: Link seems to be broken? Is there an alternative?