# Parallels between Magic and Programming than the "shoot self in foot with unsafe magical code" as in Wizard's Bane by Rick Cook?

Tags: novel, fantasy-genre

In The Wizard's Bane and the Wizardy Compiled and other books in the series by Rick Cook, a key theme is that Magic is a form of programming, and the hero of the books learns to use magic much like a programmer uses code. The core idea in Wizard's bane is that of a magic compiler, and type-safety similar to  the `Pascal` programming language reduces the danger of using magic in its raw form, similar to the real world programming languages that are "safer" than programming in raw "machine/assembly" language.

In other novels that use the idea that computer science ideas could be applied to the practice of magic in that world, or the idea of algorithms or mathematics being used as the basis for a magical system, how does that world differ from "Wizard's bane" which focuses on the "safety" of magic, via its magic-compiler idea.

(Question updated so it's answerable and specific, and not a reading-suggestion-list anymore.)

Comment: I have provided an answer, but this question is very close to being a book recommendation question since it can have many equally valid answers. It is very likely to get closed unless re-worded so that only an authoritative answer is possible

Comment: The [Young Wizards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Wizards) series has the Speech, which is very close to programming magic.  In the book "High Wizardry", Dairine takes the Oath and her laptop computer becomes her Manual.

Comment: @DVK: So you're saying we should just flag or downvote your answer?

Comment: @Tango - is it a bad answer?

Comment: @DVK: No, it isn't.  You were just being so pessimistic, as if you shouldn't have answered it.  (And this is a question that borders on one that shouldn't just be automatically closed because it might be a list question.)

Comment: @TangoOversway - doesn't take away my opinion that it needs to be polished a bit. I'm at a loss for specifics

Comment: I've attempted to fix this question.  is it better now?

Comment: It still looks like a list to me - it's now asking to _compare other novels_, rather than just _for other novels_, which still doesn't set a limit on the valid yet different answers

Comment: The moderator who closed this (Gilles) asks list questions. Are list questions allowed, or not?  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54/is-there-a-reasonably-complete-online-database-of-sf-works

Answer (score 6):

Charlie Stross's Laundry series springs to mind. It's not so much that magic is a form of programming, but that certain mathematical algorithms give one access to powers including higher dimensions where certain eldritch horrors live. The hero is a sysadmin who works for a government department charged with making sure knowledge of these algorithms is tightly controlled.

Comment: I actually rewrote my question to fit your answer, in hopes the Gods O SciFi.SE may reopen me humble question since it's not a book-list any more.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. There is one very similar to the concept you stated.

Kelly McCullough's [WebMage](http://kellymccullough.com/?page_id=55) series.

> Ravirn is not your average computer geek. A child of the Fates—literally—he’s a hacker extraordinaire who can zero in on the fatal flaw in any program. Now that twenty-first-century magic has gone digital that makes him a very talented sorcerer. But a world of problems is about to be downloaded on Ravirn—who’s just trying to pass his college midterms.
>
> Great Aunt Atropos, one of the three Fates, decides that humans having free will is really overrated and plans to rid herself of the annoyance—by coding a spell into the Fate Core, the server that rules destiny. As a hacker, Ravirn is a big believer in free will, and when he not only refuses to debug her spell but actively opposes her, all hell breaks loose.

---

As a bonus, Zelazny's Amber series in one of the latter books features a magical sentient computer that the protagonist ([Merlin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Amber#Trumps_of_Doom_.281985.29)) built.

Comment: +1 for the [Ghostwheel](http://www.ghostwheel.com/) reference.