# Does there exist a detailed list or database of science fiction works, that includes both year written and year set?

Tags: online-resources

I had it in mind to create a kind of 2D plot of classic science fiction stories, with the year it was written on one axis, and the year it's set on the other. The goal is to see if any patterns stand out in this data, such as Amara's law ("we tend to overestimate the effect of a technology in the short run and underestimate the effect in the long run").

However, in order to make such a plot I need a good source of data. A web site with a big list would do, but a proper database would be even better, if one exists. At a minimum it needs to have fields for year of publication and the year(s) in which the story is set, and it would be helpful also if it contains data about subgenre or details of any predictions made, and/or how popular the work was. I don't particularly mind if it's restricted to just films or just novels, but it should include at least all the most significant works of the 20th century. A machine readable format is greatly preferred! (I can scrape HTML if I have to.)

I note that the [internet speculative fiction database](https://www.isfdb.org/) doesn't seem to have the year in which the story is set as a field, so it doesn't work for my purpose.

(One more note: I'm not asking for big lists to be posted in the answers, please don't do that! Rather, I'd like pointers to reasonably complete resources, if they exist.)

Comment: [Internet speculative fiction database](https://www.isfdb.org) would probably be a good start

Comment: @Edlothiad I had checked that already of course, but it does not seem to be possible to download the whole database, and nor does it appear to have the year in which the story is set as a field, so it doesn't work for my purposes.

Comment: If you don't mind languages other than English, you can have a look at the [Vegetti Catalog of Fantastic Literature](http://www.fantascienza.com/catalogo/) (it is in Italian and is about works, international too, published in Italy)

Comment: Or you can try http://sfgateway.com/ but it is an online resource only; I suppose that you won't find much if you really need a downloadable database that includes the year where the work is set; I think that your best bet is to choose a limited sample of the most important and significant works and build your data set manually.

Comment: Also check this question https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/54/83101

Comment: Not a duplicate, the OP asks for a list with specific features, rather than a general SF db.